Is it knowledge about x to know that we can't know x?
I'm studying the Critique of Pure Reason. We have the claim:
We can't know anything about things in themselves

Which seems to have corollaries of the form:
We can't know x about things in themselves

Where x is any property of things in themselves. But unknowability is a property. So we get the claim:
 We can't know unknowability about things in themselves

Which can be reworded into
 We can't know that we can't know the things in themselves

Which is a contradiction in terms. How to solve this?

Maybe knowability/unknowability are not "properties" of things, because they depends on the knower and the existence of thing in themselves cannot depend on the human subject. Maybe...

Or even if unknowability is a property, we can know this property at least.

Re your "Where x is any property of things in themselves. But unknowability is a property.", perhaps unknowability is a property of human cognitive faculty and intelligibility which Kant is addressing in CPR, but it's not a property of the thing in themselves...

This was pointed out as an inconsistency in Kant's philosophy starting with Fichte. However, his claim is not as categorical as literally "anything". By "anything" he means anything substantive, anything we can know about objects of possible experience, as he puts it. But we do know that things in themselves are still subject to formal logic, for example. A trickier issue is that we can also, apparently, know that they exist, because existence is arguably a category of experience. For that, he gives a questionable argument that for there to be appearances there must be something that appears.

"A trickier issue is that we can also, apparently, know that they exist.." this is part of the criticism about the thing-in-itself. Right on target.. @Conifold

If you can’t know x, you know nothing about x.
It seems to me that saying you know that you know nothing about x is just the same as saying that you know nothing about x. What are you saying that is different here?
Not knowing, or knowing nothing, is the absence of knowing.
Despite knowing that you know nothing, there is nothing there for you to know about in the first place.

Exactly, this is referred by some as Knower paradox which, in some sense, simply involves different senses that "know" is used. +1
